# Return only a specific type of controls in a container

Tags: c#, winforms, controls, childcontrol

I use a method like this to return all the controls in a container:

```
public static IEnumerable<Control> NestedControls(this Control container, bool search_all_children = true)
{
    var stack = new Stack<Control>();
    stack.Push(container);
    do
    {
        var control = stack.Pop();

        foreach (Control child in control.Controls)
        {
            yield return child;
            stack.Push(child);
        }
    }
    while (stack.Count > 0 && search_all_children);
}
```

And this way I can get all the controls:

```
var textboxes = panel1.NestedControls().OfType<TextBox>().ToList();
```

However, with an additional code snippet in the method, I can't get only the controls of a certain type in the container. How should I update the method for a code like the one below?

```
var textboxes = panel1.NestedControls(TextBox);
```

Comment: If TextBox is a class... U can never send it like this to a method. This code can never compile.

Comment: @DA - TextBox is a type. Isn't it ?

Comment: No. An object's class defines how the object is implemented. The class defines object's internal state and the implementation of its operations. In contrast, an object's type only refers to its interface - a set of requests to which it can respond. An object can have many types, and objects of different classes can have the same type.

Comment: @DA That's worng. You can't have two classes of the same type, even if they have exactly the same implementation. In the .net world, a type is the common name for classes, records, structs, struct records and interfaces. For more information, [read this.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/types/)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419159/how-to-get-all-child-controls-of-a-windows-forms-form-of-a-specific-type-button - https://stackoverflow.com/q/65855045/14171304

Comment: @Zohar Peled. What about inheritance? you have many types hidden underneath and you can cast 2 different objects to the same type. What I said is not wrong is just a broad context.

Comment: @DA Respecftuly, I have to disagree. 
Any class is it's own type, even though it is also assignable to it's base classes, all the way up to `System.Object`. Can you assign an int to an object? of course you can. but does it mean that `System.Int32` the same type as `System.ValueType` or `System.Object`? I don't think so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can quite easily change this method to a generic one, to return only children of a specific type:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> NestedControls<T>(this Control container, bool search_all_children = true) where T : Control
{
    var stack = new Stack<Control>();
    stack.Push(container);
    do
    {
        var control = stack.Pop();

        foreach (Control child in control.Controls)
        {
            // Admittedly, not the best choice of name here...
            if(child is T childToReturn)
            {
                yield return childToReturn;
            }
            stack.Push(child);
        }
    }
    while (stack.Count > 0 && search_all_children);
}
```

Usage:

```
var textboxes = panel1.NestedControls<TextBox>();
var allNestedControls = panel1.NestedControls<Control>();
```

You can also very easily add a non-generic overload to return all nested controls without having to specify Control:

```
public static IEnumerable<Control> NestedControls(this Control container, bool search_all_children = true) 
   => NestedControls<Control>(container, search_all_children);
```